# How to delete post from wall?

Tags: c#, facebook, post, sdk

I have a problem with deleting posts from facebook wall.
I use Facebook C# SDK V4.2.1. 
Example of posting message:

```
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

//init parameters

return _app.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

And everything is ok, method Posts returns id of post.

But when I try to delete post with same id

```
 Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            if(settings.Id!=null)
                parameters.Add("id", settings.Id);
            return _app.Delete("me/feed",parameters); 

   //id  -  Facebook.JsonObject key = new Facebook.JsonObject();

   //key.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,object>("id",id));
```

An error has been occurred:

> (OAuthException) Invalid token: "me".  An ID has already been specified.
>   Stack trace:
>    at Facebook.FacebookApp.MakeRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, Uri requestUrl, Byte[] postData, String contentType, Type resultType, Boolean restApi) in d:\Projects\facebooksdk\Source\Facebook\FacebookApp.cs:line 800

and so on.

I tried to remove token "me", to past instead of token userId,result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply with _app.Delete(settings.id).

Answer (score 0):

I guess delete is not allowed by facebook ....as a security restriction placed by facebook to avoid any exploitation